# If $f: I \to R$ is continuous and I is sequentially compact. Prove that if $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n) = L $ then $\exists x \in I$ s.t $f(x) = L$ Verify

Tags: real-analysis

Proof:
Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n) = L $, $x_n \to x_0$ means that $f(x_0) = L$ (is this true given continuity?). $x_n$ has a subsequence $x_{nk}$ which also converges to $x_0$. Since $I$ is sequentially compact $x_0 \in I$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, ordering everything a little:
Since $(x_n)_n\subset I$, where $I$ is sequentially compact, then exists a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_k$ such that $x_{n_k}\to x$ for some $x\in I$. Now using the continuity of $f$, we have $f(x_{n_k})\to f(x)$. Since $f(x_n)$ is convergent and converges for $L$, then any convergent subsequence has to converge for the same limit and by the uniqueness of the limit we have that $f(x)=L$.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily have that $x_n$ converges (example : $I = [-1,1]$ , $x_n = (-1)^n$ ) however you have that there exist a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ of $x_n$ converging to a certain $x_\infty \in I$ therefore the following holds

$$L = \lim_{n\to +\infty}{f(x_n)} = \lim_{k\to+\infty}{f(x_{n_k})} = f(\lim_{k\to +\infty}{x_{n_k}}) = f(x_\infty)$$

Where in the third equality I used the continuity of f